# How to get brackets without apostrophes from the writeStream?

Tags: quotes, smalltalk, squeak

I tried to get my brakets back from the *wirteStream*. Sadly the writeStream set two punctuation marks (apostrophes) before and after the brackets.

Could someone help me? I found the mistake for this in the class String in *printOn* and mainly in *storeOn*.

Have you an idea to solve it? I thought on RegEx... but maybe someone has another methode or solution.

```
| stream |
'()' printOn: (stream := '' writeStream).
stream contents = '()'.
```

Regards, 
bartak.

Comment: hmm, the problem comes up, when I try 'ANYTHING' with apothropes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `String`'s `#printOn:` explicitly calls `#storeOn:`

```
printOn: aStream 
    "Print inside string quotes, doubling inbedded quotes."

    self storeOn: aStream
```

You could do it the other way around:

```
(stream := '' writeStream) nextPutAll: '()'.
```

Comment: Thank you, Tobias. I want to show the trace of methods for other users here, so I listed printOn in my explanation. Next time I will show only the important method. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That's because `String>>printOn:` will print "a string as a string", i.e. it will be quoted *again*. Solution: don't use `#printOn:` but rather `Stream>>nextPutAll:` or `Stream>>print:`.

**Clarification**:

`#print` is supposed to be sent to the stream, not to `ByteString`:

`'' writeStream print: '()'.`

Comment: Thank you. nextPutAll works. If I use print, it raises ByteString>>print .